# Sublime Text search status and cancel

Tags: search, sublimetext

Is there a clear way to see if a file search is currently running and/or to cancel the search process?

I've seen questions in other forums like [here](http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&p=25500) and [here](http://sublimetext.userecho.com/topic/100316-/), yet no clear answers..